# Why the parent process does not block at reading from pipe operation?

Tags: unix, pipe, fork

I have the following piece of code:

```
int main(int c, char** v) 
{
  int p[2], n;
  char s[10] = "ceva";
  pipe(p);
  n = fork();
  if(n == 0) 
  {
    close(p[0]);
    printf("Before\n");
    if(c > 2)
      execlp("grep","grep",v[1],v[2],NULL);
      strcpy(s, "after");   
    write(p[1], s, 6);
    close(p[1]);
    exit(0);
   } 
  close(p[1]);
  read(p[0], s, 6);
  close(p[0]);
  printf("%s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

When running the code using `./grep grep grep.c` I would expect the parent process to block at the line containing `read(p[0], s, 6);` since the child process din not write anything in the pipe nor closed the writing end.

Could you please indicate me where I am not thinking correctly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The child execs grep, which runs to completion and exits, closing the write end of the pipe. Since the parent has also closed both ends of the pipe, the read returns.

Comment: Ok, so the exec process is the closing the write  end of the pipe. :) Thanks a lot. :)